# removeFromSuperView don't work on iOS 8

Tags: ios

I'm adding a view over my main view like this:

```
self.voteResult = [[voteResultViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"voteResultViewController" bundle:nil];      
    UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [mainWindow addSubview:[self.viewControllerForPresentation view]];
    [self.viewControllerForPresentation presentViewController:self.voteResult animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

And then removing it with this:

```
 [self.viewControllerForPresentation.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Works in iOS 7, but not longer in iOS 8, do I need to do anything different?

Comment: Why are you adding the view yourself and also using `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`? That method presents the view controller, which should cause the view to be displayed appropriately. You should then use `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` to dismiss the controller, and that will also remove the view.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing too much work here. You're adding `self.viewControllerForPresentation.view` to the view yourself using `-addSubview:`, but you're also presenting the view controller using `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`. That method presents the view controller in question, which should then take care of adding the view to the view hierarchy. To remove the view, you'd use `-dismissViewControllerAniamted:completion:` and that in turn should remove the view appropriately.

In short, *either* add and remove the view yourself using `-addSubview:` and `-removeFromSuperview`, *or* present the view controller that owns the view using `-presentViewController:animated:completion:` and dismiss it using `-dismissViewControllerAniamted:completion:`. Don't to do both.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:voteResult completion:nil];
```